# can't write '@' symbol or other CTRL+ALT+KEY combinations

Tags: python, pyside2, qwebengineview

I am trying to login to a website with the QWebEngineView. When I try to write in my E-Mail, I can't write the '@' symbol (CTRL+ALT+Q). I noticed that it doesn't work with any type of CTRL+ALT+KEY combination. I can paste the @ symbol when I copy it from outside. I use Windows 10

It works on other computers.
It works on the normal Google Chrome browser.

Here is a code sample:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the log

```
DEBUG:root:================================================================================
<PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifiers object at 0x000001FACCDCD740>
DEBUG:root:{"key": 16777249, "modifiers": "QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier", "nativeScanCode": 29, "nativeVirtualKey": 17, "nativeModifiers": 514, "text": "", "isAutoRepeat": false, "count": 1}
DEBUG:root:================================================================================
<PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifiers object at 0x000001FACCDCD740>
DEBUG:root:{"key": 16777251, "modifiers": "", "nativeScanCode": 56, "nativeVirtualKey": 18, "nativeModifiers": 518, "text": "", "isAutoRepeat": false, "count": 1}     
DEBUG:root:================================================================================
<PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifiers object at 0x000001FACCDCD740>
DEBUG:root:{"key": 64, "modifiers": "", "nativeScanCode": 16, "nativeVirtualKey": 81, "nativeModifiers": 518, "text": "@", "isAutoRepeat": false, "count": 1}
DEBUG:root:================================================================================
<PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifiers object at 0x000001FACCDCD740>
DEBUG:root:{"key": 16777249, "modifiers": "QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier", "nativeScanCode": 29, "nativeVirtualKey": 17, "nativeModifiers": 514, "text": "", "isAutoRepeat": false, "count": 1}
DEBUG:root:================================================================================
<PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifiers object at 0x000001FACCDCD740>
DEBUG:root:{"key": 16777251, "modifiers": "", "nativeScanCode": 312, "nativeVirtualKey": 18, "nativeModifiers": 16777794, "text": "", "isAutoRepeat": false, "count": 1}
DEBUG:root:================================================================================
<PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifiers object at 0x000001FACCDCD740>
DEBUG:root:{"key": 64, "modifiers": "", "nativeScanCode": 16, "nativeVirtualKey": 81, "nativeModifiers": 578, "text": "@", "isAutoRepeat": false, "count": 1}
```

The first time I tried pressing CTRL+ALT+Q and the second time I pressed AltGr + Q

The script comes from [this URL](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/75cd61923daf60573f8e04a022e06c92)

Comment: The combination depends on the keyboard, what language does your OS use? For example, I have to press Alt Gr + 2 to get "@"

Comment: I am using  the Qwertz (German) layout. You can either press AltGr + Q or CTRL + ALT + Q  to get the "@" or other symbols. None of them works, only copy paste. One thing I could imagine is to add a hotkey and then the program pastes the "@"

Comment: try add  `QtCore.QLocale.setDefault(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.Germany))` after `app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)`, what is your OS?

Comment: Do you have a similar problem with google chrome? Also you could use the following code: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/blob/master/templates/TemplateQWebEngineView.py changing `https://www.qt.io`  for `https://www.google.com/` , and try to write "@" in the google search

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I get an error when adding the line. I changed the ".Germany" to ".German" and the program started, but the "@" doesn't work.

Comment: I tested it on several websites with the template. It doesn't work

Comment: Don't you have the same problem with google-chrome?

Comment: For me it is a Qt bug, I recommend you report it. The problem has nothing to do with oauth2 or spotipy (your code is just noise in your current post), but it seems that QtWebEngineView does not allow writing "@", in my case I can write "@"

Comment: It works on the normal Chrome browser. I tested the ALT + NUMPAD combination (ALT+64) and it works fine in the QWebView.

Comment: mmm, that proves that there is a bug, I already pointed out to you in my previous comment. Note: don't use the term QWebView but rather QWebEngineView (there is another class with that name so it can cause confusion).

Comment: I am going to try to implement a workaround but since I don't have that problem I hope that you will give me a clear and quick feedback

Comment: I'll do that :), Thanks!

Comment: I have modified your example since as I point out it is unnecessarily long, just to confirm: can't you just write "@" in the input of "google.com"?

Comment: I can't write the @ in the input of google.

Comment: Try the following code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/75cd61923daf60573f8e04a022e06c92 and write "@" and tell me what you get in the console

Comment: Log:
DEBUG:root:text: , key: 16777249
DEBUG:root:text: , key: 16777251
DEBUG:root:text: @, key: 64
So the @ key gets recognized

Comment: mmm, have you tested your application on another PC?

Comment: What do you get when you press "Alt + 64"?

Comment: I tested it on another one and it works there. I also didn't find anything on the internet, so I think the problem is my PC

Comment: When I press ALT+64 on the numpad it works

Comment: I know it works but tell me what you get in the log, my idea is to catch the event "Ctrl + Alt + Q" and exchange it for "Alt + 64" but for this I need the feedback from the log

Comment: DEBUG:root:text: , key: 16777251
DEBUG:root:text: , key: 54
DEBUG:root:text: , key: 52
DEBUG:root:text: @, key: 0

Comment: It would also be good if your post indicates that it fails on your PC but it works on others.

Comment: I have updated the script to give me more details, so please test what it says: "Alt + 64" and place the log in the same post since the SO comments section has limitations

Comment: I posted everything